# Are we allowed to publish Xamarin iOS apps with the Mono Interpreter enabled?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, mono

I realize that with the recent developments [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/introducing-xamarin-ios-interpreter/) we can:

> interpret at run time some C# parts of your application while compiling the rest ahead of time as usual.

This has a lot of benefits, and enables us to use packages like ML.NET to perform Machine Learning, and Roslyn that allows you to compile C# offline (without using a web service).

I know there are several limitations right now that are mentioned in the article, such as a really big package sizes. But is there any reason that an app built with features using the interpreter would be rejected during submission?

Comment: Did you manage to get an App uploaded to the Store? Mind sharing your experience in terms of performance and rejection?

Comment: Haven’t tried yet. Let me know if you are successful in this though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The final arbiter to the Apple App Store is Apple of course, and they have in the past silently added checks,  but today we known of no reason why it shouldn't be accepted.

Today they are part of the Xamarin iOS's internal submission tests, and so far we haven't seen any rejections.